# VS Code does not receive "P" when pressing Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code

The keyboard shortcut for the command pallet (`Ctrl+Shift+P`) has stopped working in VS Code. When I go to `File -> Preferences -> Keyboad Shortcuts` I can confirm that only the default keybindings are present for the `Ctrl+Shift+P` key combination.

However, when I click `Record Keys` and type `Ctrl+Shift+P` then only `"Ctrl+Shift"` shows in the keybindings search box. So it seems that VS Code is never receiving the `P` when `Ctrl+Shift` is held down, but it *does* receive the P for other combinations (for example, `Ctrl+P`).

Clearly something is preventing VS Code from receiving the full key combination. How do I identify it?

Comment: Have you confirmed that other programs can see Ctrl+Shift+P?  In Firefox, for example, that combination opens a private window.  Does that work?

Comment: I tried in FireFox and it does NOT receive it either :-\

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I also found that this only impacts my LEFT keys. If I use any of the right-keys then it works correctly. For example right CTRL + left SHIFT + P is fine. The same is true if I swap which CTRL and SHIFT, as long as I don't use left and left.

Comment: Can confirm the same issue on Firefox. Left Shift+Left Ctrl+P doesn't work. Any other combo does. Found this https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/jhq4wt/ctrl_shift_p_not_working_anymore/. Guess we are not alone but no solution.

Answer (score 3):

Given the additional information (in a comment) that Firefox also cannot see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, it seems clear that the problem **does not lie with VSCode** itself.

That leaves three main possibilities:

1. There is a bug in the operating system or keyboard driver.
2. Some other software is intercepting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
3. The keyboard hardware is malfunctioning.

To tell which, first reset the keyboard software stack.  That can be done in various ways, in order of increasing intrusiveness and completeness:

- Press and release each of the keys in question.
- Press and release all of the adjacent keys.
- Unplug and re-plug the keyboard (if not a laptop).
- Plug in another keyboard.
- Warm reboot of the OS.
- Completely power off and then power on the computer.

If one of the above steps *does* resolve the problem, then that's good in the short term, but the problem may recur.  Options in that case include upgrading the keyboard drivers, switching keyboards, and upgrading or switching operating systems.

If the problem persists even with a different keyboard, then I would suspect hypothesis #2 is correct.  It's hard to provide specific advice on how to further diagnose that without knowing more about your setup, but the basic approach I would take is to stop running programs one by one, checking each time if the key sequence now works.